# How to make (3 * 4) graph plot in my case?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I make polynomial regression in sklearn.
How to add another 3 lines with graphs in my case?
I've experimented with plt.subplot and plt.subplots, but had failed.

Head of dataframe ([full df link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10psThTElA6el_pOap8aYzljCRSXtkvXi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113752785996722037226&rtpof=true&sd=true)):

|  | first_day | mentor_cnt | mentee_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-03-06 00:00:00 | 8 | 8 |
| 1 | 2021-04-19 00:00:00 | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 2021-05-14 00:00:00 | 9 | 9 |
| 3 | 2021-05-25 00:00:00 | 9 | 9 |
| 4 | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 2021-06-15 00:00:00 | 9 | 9 |

My code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

df_p = pd.read_excel('./full_df.xlsx')
x_p = df_p['mentee_cnt'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y_p = df_p['mentor_cnt'].to_numpy()

x_p_train, x_p_test, y_p_train, y_p_test = train_test_split(x_p, y_p, test_size=0.2)

degrees = [1, 2, 3, 4]

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
for i in range(len(degrees)):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, len(degrees), i+1)
    plt.setp(ax, xticks=(), yticks=())

    polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degrees[i], include_bias=False)
    linear_regression = LinearRegression()
    pipeline = Pipeline(
        [
            ("polynomial_features", polynomial_features),
            ("linear_regression", linear_regression)
        ]
    )
    model_poly = pipeline.fit(x_p_train, y_p_train)

    y_p_train_pred = model_poly.predict(x_p_train)
    y_p_test_pred = model_poly.predict(x_p_test)

    RMSE_test = cross_val_score(pipeline, y_p_test.reshape(-1, 1), y_p_test_pred, scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
    RMSE_train = cross_val_score(pipeline, y_p_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_p_train_pred, scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error", cv=10)

    model_poly_coef = model_poly.named_steps['linear_regression'].coef_
    model_poly_indepent = model_poly.named_steps['linear_regression'].intercept_

    plt.plot(x_p_test, pipeline.predict(x_p_test), label="Model", color="r")
    plt.scatter(x_p_test, y_p_test, label="Test values")
    plt.xlabel("mentee")
    plt.ylabel("mentor")
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.title(
        f'''Degree{1}\nLinearRegression predict vs. test values
RMSE_test = {-RMSE_test.mean():.3f}(+/-{RMSE_test.std():.3f})
RMSE_train = {-RMSE_train.mean():.3f}(+/-{RMSE_train.std():.3f})
mentor_cnt = {model_poly_indepent:.3f} + {model_poly_coef[0]:.3f} * mentee_cnt'''
        )

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Graphs, that I need to add in my graph plt:

```
# Second line with graphs
residuals_poly = y_p_test - pipeline.predict(x_p_test)
res_p = stats.probplot(residuals_poly, plot=plt)
stat_residuals_poly, p_residuals_poly = stats.shapiro(residuals_poly)
plt.ylabel('Residuals')
plt.xlabel('Excepted normal Value')
plt.title('Normal probability plot of residuals\nShapiro: stat_residuals=%.3f, p_residuals=%.3f' %(stat_residuals_poly, p_residuals_poly))
plt.show()

# Third line
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [8, 5]
sns.histplot(data=residuals_poly, kde=True, bins=5)
plt.title('Normal probability plot of residuals')
plt.show()
   
#Fourth line
sns.scatterplot(y=residuals_poly, x=pipeline.predict(x_p_test))
plt.title('Predicted vs. Residual Values')
plt.ylabel('Residuals')
plt.show()
```